# Calculate the radio of the earth with a stick like Eratosthenes

Tags: experimental-physics, earth

I read about how to calculate the radius of the earth like Eratosthenes, but they often said that I should measure the shadow of a stick (usually is a stick) at the time when the solar noon occurs in MY location. However, i think it should be measured at the time that the solar noon occurs in the TROPIC (i mean, if the sun noon occurs for example at 12:00 in tropic, then at the hour that is on that moment in my location i do measure), because is there  and on that time that there's no shadows and hence i can calculate the radius followin the draw of the image). I hope i did explain me.[image]

Comment: Mm ok, what I understood is that solar noon occurs at the same time in different places as long as they are located on the same meridian, right?

Comment: @FernandoMartínez Yes, solar noon occurs at the same time on the same meridian.

Comment: Thank you very much!